# What, if anything, does a blue-and-white American flag mean?

Tags: united-states, flag

[image]

I saw this flag, consisting of a field of 13 blue and white horizontal stripes, with a blue canton containing 50 white stars, as one of about two dozen flags flying over a booth selling flags in the US. What, if anything, does this flag represent?

I've found that a traditional or blue-and-white American flag with an extra light-blue blue stripe across the middle represents support for law enforcement, but nothing about this flag.  Does it have a meaning, or is it just a manufacturing error?

Comment: Do you have some context? Where did you see this flag?

Comment: @divibisan, saw it as one of about two dozen flags flying over a booth selling flags.  So, no meaningful context beyond it being for sale in the United States.  (Hence the suggestion of it being a manufacturing error -- someone might have a stack of a hundred oddball flags they want to get rid of.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see what so far seems to be an artistic rendition choice belongs on SE.Po.  I don't see any question re. politics or policy here.  Ask yourself:  would this be acceptable if this question was about colors chosen to show the flag of Micronesia instead?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Flags are by definition political. If someone saw a flag that resembled the flag of Micronesia, except differed in the colors used, then yes, it would be on topic to ask whether there is a political meaning to the flag.

Comment: From the website army.mil is the following... The wear guidance for wear of the U.S. Flag is the same for all camouflage patterns of the Army Combat Uniform. AR 670-1, para 21-18 states, "All Soldiers will wear the full-color U.S. flag embroidered insignia on utility and organizational uniforms, unless deployed or in a field environment. Soldiers will wear the subdued tactical flag insignia while deployed or in a field environment."

Comment: @Acccumulation The OP hasn't even *shown* that the question has any political implications, he's merely asking if it has.  I realize that a large volume of questions are USA centric, but this is delving into *trivia* from the POV of everyone else.  Other questions do not have that easy a time not getting closed here.  Anyway, you don't have to agree with me, I've stated my reason for closure, that's all (without DV).  No skin off my butt if it stays open.  And.. the one comment pointing at an answer...  not political in nature.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'm not an expert on SE, but it seems to me that the purpose of the site is to ask question, even if whether there's something relevant to the SE is part of the question. I would consider "Is this script Japanese?" to be on topic for the Japanese SE, even if the answer is "no". And most SE questions are trivia for the majority of the population.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica We handled many vexillological questions before and most of them received interesting answers.

Comment: You can buy flags for US sports teams that render the Stars and Stripes in the colour of the team, although usually with a logo - [here's the Oakland Raiders](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Wholesale-American-flag-with-NFL-team_1600057045891.html) I don't know enough to say who's the most likely blue and white team.

Comment: https://www.redbubble.com/i/poster/American-Flag-STARS-and-STRIPES-USA-America-Navy-Blue-on-White-by-TOMSREDBUBBLE/33839637.LVTDI claims Tom Hill (who doesn't appear to be famous) designed this version of the flag.

Comment: A search for blue and white American flag turns up similar ones with no further identification. My guess is it’s the military’s mono color flag decal, rendered in other colors to suit your fashion

Comment: @divibisan I've seen this too. Mostly in rural areas. I haven't seen it in other colors that I can recall.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this flag has any particular meaning or significance. The only use of it that I'm aware of is as an unofficial hybrid version of the flags of the United States and Greece, as used in [this advert](https://www.adsoftheworld.com/media/print/fit_in_3) for a language education company. As H2ONaCl mentioned in a comment, the US Army authorises the wearing of a 'subdued tactical flag insignia' while soldiers are deployed in [AR 670-1 21-19](https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/ARN30302-AR_670-1-000-WEB-1.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A92%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C328%2C0%5D), but this is generally olive or black, not blue and white.

The only other possibility I can think of is that possibly due to how the flag was hanging when you saw it, it could have been possible to mistake the design of one of the following similar flags:

- [The Kimball/Maguire Flag](http://www.loeser.us/flags/utah_note_2.html), as reconstructed from a written description of a flag used to represent the Deseret Territory - a provisional state of the US proposed by Mormon settlers - is similar, but with a large star in the canton surrounded by a circle of smaller stars.
- The flag of the [Society of the Cincinnati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_the_Cincinnati) again has thirteen blue & white stripes, but the canton contains a circle of fourteen white stars surrounding an eagle.
- The flag of [Ambazonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambazonia), a self-declared state internationally recognised as a part of Cameroon - probably less likely given you saw the flag for sale in the United States. This consists of nine blue & white stripes, with a dove in the canton surrounded by a circle of gold stars.

Comment: Wouldn't have been any of your alternatives: the stars were clearly in a grid pattern, not a circle.